# In MySQL, replace all the data for every record for only one column

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
    A    |    B    |    C    <----columns
x   0    |    -    |    -
y   0    |    -    |    -
z   0    |    -    |    -
```

I want to replace all the 0 with -, something like a foreach would do it, but I want to do it with SQL (if possible).

In my actual problem here theres hundreds of rows, so by hand would be bad lol. I could probably crack it with some php but I suspect theres a thingy in MySQL that does this.

Comment: Clearly Ive been up too long.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just mean

```
update mytable set A="-" where A="0";
```

?

Answer (score 1):

`update table tablename set A="-" where A="0"`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
UPDATE mytable
SET a = 123
WHERE a = 0
```

Or replace 123 with whatever you want, like '-'.